# links will not work on laravel app with azure server

Tags: laravel, azure, broken-links

Hey folks any advice would be so helpful. My first time deploying to azure. The app deploys nice and slick, but i find that my app opens to the index page, but will not link to any others.

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
s

The path is set to public in the application settings
i have scaled up the ressources, added a web-config file then removed it again, the app functions with local host... I'm sure this is not the first time this has been an issue... Thanks

```
.env file
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ymq4IuQRQdVHqcamf8wMfuqo1IwbpVTcZZrBZ3CnEyo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://jobquest1030.scm.azurewebsites.net

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=joboard
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Does your Azure setup deploy to App Service on `Linux` or App Service on `Windows`?

Comment: it deploys to app service on windows